# Is there any option to edit default netsuite calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, netsuite

I want to count number of weeks e.g 03-07-2017 to 09-07-2017 is 1st week and to the calendar view just as given in the picture. Is there any option to do it through scripting or functionally

[image]

Comment: This is a page to help you developing. Users will not write code for you but they will help you understand and fix code. Show us what you have already done and we are able to help you.

Comment: I coundn't find any api to edit the calendar. So i was asking if it was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not hard to calculate with time. Take a look at moment.js, you have a lot of date/time functionality there.

But you don't specify what you actually want to do. Do you want to number the weeks from the beginning of the year, ISO style? Do you want to number the weeks within a specific month? If so, what is your definition of what is the first week? I am making a guess from your illustration that you count the first week where all days fall within the current week is week 1. But do you start your week on Sunday or Monday?
Or do you actually want to display the week number in the calendar, like in the illustration? Unless you create your own date picker, I am pretty sure that is not possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will figure it out with Moment.js